# Can I know z-order column?

Tags: databricks, delta-lake

Is there any way to know which column was used for z-ordering for a given table? I've tried multiple commands like `describe` and `describe extended` along with viewing the delta log. I found no information which column was used to perform the optimization.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find this information in the [history of the table](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-utility.html#retrieve-delta-table-history).  Filter by `operation = 'OPTIMIZE'` then the `operationParameters` column will be a struct with fields `predicate` and `zOrderBy` (string encoding a JSON array of ZOrder columns)...

For example, when I optimized table by with ZOrder by `rnd` column

[image]